# matching folders by name, selecting them and copy them to another location in R

Tags: r, directory

The real problem: I have a dataset (.csv) with 3000 entries, each one has a unique id. The information of this dataset was extracted from images that are stored in a server in folders. There are more them 30 thousands folders containing these images in our server, but only those 3K had been used so far. Each folder has an ID associated in its name that matches with the ones in the csv table, so these folders are trackable. So, I want to found in the server those 3 thousand folders that I used in the dataset, matching them by id and copying them to another place, to use those images in other analysis. I'm new in R and have been trying some solutions with some simple example in my computer. I have created a set of folders (10) and managed to store those 5 dummy ids in a object called file, however I cant copy them. This is what I have done so far, if anyone can help to get it work I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

`id <- c("id01", "id02", "id03", "id04", "id05")`

`file <- vector()`

`for (i in id) { file <- c(file, list.files(path = "~/R testes/Manipulacao de pastas e arquivos/teste/origem", pattern = i, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)) }`

`file`

`file.copy("file", "~/R testes/Manipulacao de pastas e arquivos/teste/destino")`

I get the following error message: problem copying .\file to C:/Users/desuo/Documents\R testes\Manipulacao de pastas e arquivos\teste\destino\file: No such file or directory[1] FALSE

Comment: Maybe you just need to unquote `"file"` inside of `file.copy`?

Comment: yeah, lapply didn't work either. Looks like it is something related about dealing the right way with the object "file" (a list with the directories inside). removing quote didn't work as well. Thank you!